# Is there some way to specify a custom deserializer for a type that is nested inside an Optional for Jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, option-type

I have some types which need to be handled with their own special deserializers and serializers, but how do I instruct Jackson to use them when the type is nested inside an Optional?

I am using the JDK8Module which works great for any type not needing any special handling. The @JsonDeserialize and @JsonSerialize annotations don't seem to have any way to apply to the value inside an Optional when they are used on an Optional field:

```
 @JsonDeserialize(?????)
 Optional<SpecialType> myField
```

Comment: Just a wild shot: What about the `@JsonCreator` as described at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations ?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding how to apply this to the situation. How do I specify for that specific field to use the creator? It seems to me that you write this method in some other class but it's not clear to me to instruct jackson to use a delegate-based creator defined in another class to populate a specific field in my Pojo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to accomplish this is:

```
 @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=CustomDeserializer.class)
 Optional<SpecialType> myField
```

There was a [defect](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8/issues/31) that prevented this working which was fixed in 2.7.4.